# How to update data without wiping all other data in Firestore with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, updates

I am working on an app and I am trying to update a bool to true, I tried `updateData()` but it just wipes the whole documents' field, so if anyone knows a better way please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setData() function instead of add() method.

```
void createRecord() async {
  await databaseReference.collection("books")
      .document("1")
      .setData({
        'title': 'Flutter',
        'description': 'Dart'
      },merge=true);// setData sets the data of a document, if it does not exists, then it creates a document with the specified name


}
```